# Rosmake rosconsole fail on OSx Lion

Tags: macos, rosmake, rosconsole, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying building ros under osx Lion by following the tutorial reported on the ROS website. I have installed macports and the latest version of XCode.

I applied the patch reported here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3626
Otherwise the compilation of rosconsole still fails with the following error:

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package rosconsole
[rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build
cd build && make -l8
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/librosconsole.dylib
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: library not found for -llog4cxx
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [../lib/librosconsole.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that it is not able to find log4cxx. Otherwise it is installed through macport and the `.profile` file is configured for seeing it. This is my `.profile`:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2011-10-21_at_13:20:04: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

# ROS
source /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/setup.bash
[ -f ~/.git-bash-completion.sh ] && . ~/.git-bash-completion.sh

# define colors
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
 
export CPATH=/opt/local/include:/usr/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/
```

Is there a know solution?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12153/rosmake-rosconsole-fail-on-osx-lion/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are not married to Macports, William has also done a lot of good work getting ROS up and running using [Homebrew](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew). This is how I installed ROS on Lion and it was pretty painless.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2011-12-05**:
You really shouldn't because both ports and brew will want to install some of the same stuff (e.g., cmake, cairo, boost, etc) depending on what you need. You may get conflicts with software building with one version of boost but trying to run with another (or visa versa). So it is generally not done

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-05**:
@Kevin Can MacPort and Homebrew coexist? I'm using macport for other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to build it with Xcode?  I would think you just need to add the path '/opt/local/lib' to your library link path in Xcode.

Here is a stack overflow talking about linking external libraries with Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode

EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question.  Try running `LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib make` while you are in the directory given by `roscd rosconsole`.  I think your environment variables should have covered this but maybe they have typos or something and this will show you that if rosconsole then compiles.

Also check to make sure something like /opt/local/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib exitsts.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-05**:
@William I will try it, where do I have to set this stuff? Do you have an idea of what can be wrong in my `.profile` file? I checked it and I didn't find typos. I reported it in the question. Thanks

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-12-05**:
I think so, I would manually add the CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS to make sure it isn't some typos or something in your environment.

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-05**:
@William Do you think that I have a more general problem? Rosdep also fails to find eigen, tinyxml, yaml-cpp and they are all installed through macport

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-05**:
@William Hi, fixed it by dowloading log4cxx from source, compiling and installing them...I don't think it's the good solution, but it worked...

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-11-30**:
@William Hi, no I don't. I'm trying to build it by command line...according to the tutorial that you can find on the ROS website. Currently `/opt/local/lib` is in both `$LIBRARY_PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thanks